# Python multiprocessing ForkingPickler issue

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm working a socket client well really 2 clients, one sends messages and the other receives messages. There are two socket server, one is listening for commands and the other is providing responses.
I'm trying to write a double client, which allows me to send messages and will spin up another process to receive messages from response server. They aren't always synchronous. I create this little class that I'd like it to spin up a process to listen responses, but I'm stuck with this error when I run it:

```
ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle module objects
```

The little program is as follows:

```
import socket
import logging
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process, Manager, Pipe
import traceback
import re


class Geisy3:
    received_messages = []
    dbg_process = None

    def __init__(self):
        print('hello')

    def connect(self, ip, port):
        s = socket.socket()
        logging.basicConfig(filename="geisy-3.log", level=logging.INFO,
                            format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
        logging.info('Icci debug IP: %s, cmd port: %s', ip, port)
        s.connect((ip, port))
        logging.info('Socket connection established on %s:%s', ip, port)

        with Manager() as manager:
            self.received_messages = manager.list()
            self.dbg_process = Process(target=self.socket_receiver, args=(self, s, self.received_messages, logging))
            self.dbg_process.start()
            self.dbg_process.join()

        print('Debug process started')

    def socket_receiver(self, soc, received_messages, logging):
        try:
            while 1:
                logging.debug('Socket listener is awaiting message')
                raw_response = soc.recv(256)
                logging.debug('RAW Msg recv [%s]: %s', 20001, raw_response)


        except Exception as e:
            logging.FATAL('Exception %s:', e)
            logging.FATAL('Debug listner exception occured %s', traceback.format_exc())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = Geisy3()

    i.connect('98.1.24.40', 20001)
    time.sleep(500)
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. Is it because windows spawns rather than forks?

Can I actually have a method in the class that starts, joins and then effectively another that kills the process ?

Comment: From the error message, it seems to be a sender side issue.  So, are you seeing this error on the receiver end (in the code you have posted) or on the  sender end?  Also, can you post the code for the sender?

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 parts (I only control 2 on my end). I'm getting this on my end while trying to setup a listener. This code works as soon as I take it outside of the class. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around on how this should be implemented inside a class. The sender from end we can actually ignore completely (it works fine and its another class). The sever to which the above listener connects sends heartbeat messages, so I should be able to have the process running and have it print those messages.

Like I said as standalone script without class it works great, jut the problem is that I need to embedded that within another program hence I thought of putting it inside a class to have little more control from that other program.